# Non-exhaustive patterns n-tuple function

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have been done a program to university, based on changing image pixels.

But i don't know how to solve this problem.

I convert the [String] with all the pixels in a 3-tuple list, and then i change all the pixels to Red, but when i execute the program it seems to be a problem with de patterns, the error on terminal is
"Non-exhaustive patterns in function toRed"

and there is the function toRed

```
toRed :: [String] -> [(String, String, String)]
toRed [] = []
toRed (x:y:z:xs) = (x,"0","0") : toRed xs
```

The program execute, and save the outFile, but don't convert all the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching two cases:

- empty list - `[]`
- list with at least three elements - `x:y:z:xs`

This leaves two cases that you haven't matched:

- list with exactly one element - `[x]`
- list with exactly two elements - `[x, y]`

Keep in mind that the above is only *local* description of cases. Since your function is recursive, and subtracts three elements every time it recurs, those cases actually translate to "*list of length 3n+1*" and "*list of length 3n+2*" respectively.

I can't tell you exactly what to do in those cases, because I don't know the nature of your problem, but including them will prevent errors.

For example, you may want to treat these two cases exactly the same way as you treat an empty list:

```
toRed :: [String] -> [(String, String, String)] 
toRed [] = [] 
toRed [x] = [] 
toRed [x, y] = [] 
toRed (x:y:z:xs) = (x,"0","0") : toRed xs
```

If handling these cases this way makes sense to you, you may want to consider combining all three "empty" cases in a single catch-all case:

```
toRed :: [String] -> [(String, String, String)] 
toRed (x:y:z:xs) = (x,"0","0") : toRed xs
toRed _ = []
```

Comment: And if you don't think that case is valid and actually want the program to crash if the list length is not a multiple of 3, to indicate that something is seriously wrong, you can include a case with `toRed _ = error "toRed: List length is not a multiple of 3"` instead.

Comment: It might also make sense to treat any single/pair of leftover bytes as a pixel whose blue and green component you don't care about; `toRed [] = []; toRed (x:y:z:xs) = (x,"0", "0") : toRed xs; toRed (x:xs) = [(x,"0", "0")]`.